# Pivotal Cloud Foundry with Mongo DB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

We are planning to use mongo db for an application that is deployed in cloud foundry. I came across a [link](http://docs.pivotal.io/mongodb/index.html) which talks about limitations of this integration. Does Cloud Foundry not support Mongo DB as a managed service or does not support mongo db even if external connection parameters are used?

Answer (score 2):

I have used CloudFoundry for learning Spring Boot and Cloud deployment, and deployed 2 Spring Boot apps one with MongoDB service provided by CF and another configured externally.

In both case the MongoDB service provider is MongoLab (mongolab.com)

CF provides MongoDB via MongoLab service as well you can get MongoDBasS from MongoLab.com and configure your app to use MongoDb.

The link which you posted refers to "p-mongodb" service, which doesn't exists anymore. 
I ran `cf marketplace` and don't see `p-mongodb` available. I guess Pivotal removed the old `p-mongodb` service with the new `mongolab` service.

Checkout this link - https://console.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/mongolab.

PS: Here is my deployed app - http://blogaggregator.cfapps.io

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this suitable to be used in an enterprise production setup ?

Comment: I cannot comment on this since I am beginner. But I think it is suitable, because many others are using it.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay , appreciate your help

Comment: Having connection issue with mongodb on cloudfoundry, but works fine on local machine. Is there a cure?